# Rails - Show matching records

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-4.1

How do I execute a Rails query to show all Exams where a match exists in StudentExam? I have 3 tables, Student, Exam and StudentExam. The first two are self descriptive. The StudentExam tables has 3 fields: student_id, exam_id and status. I want to search StudentExam for a specific user ID (say 1) and show all matching Exams for this student.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have a join table then, a has_and_belongs_to_many or something? In this case

```
@user = User.find(1)
@exams = @user.exams
```

or if that's not the case and the third table is based off a model then the preferred way

```
@exams = Exam.joins(:student_exams).where("student_exams.student_id = ?" 1)
```

also

```
@exams = StudentExam.where(student_id: 1).each.collect { |row| row.exam }
```

**Edit**

To collect them both, probably something like

```
@exams = StudentExam.where(student_id: 1).each.collect { |row| [row, row.exam] }
```

Comment: How do I also show fields from both Exam and StudentExam? It is only showing fields from Exam.

Answer (score 0):

```
select se.*, e.*
  from studentexam se
  join exam e
    on se.exam_id = e.id
 where se.student_id = 'X'
```

Replace "e.id" above with whatever field on the EXAM table indicates the exam id associated with the EXAM_ID field of the EXAM table.

Replace 'X' with the student_id of interest.

Change e.* in the select list if you want to select some but not all of the columns from the EXAM table.